# CSS stylesheets at top or bottom? or How to solve blank page issue?

Tags: css, rendering, progressive

I have been putting stylesheets on top (between `<head></head>`) of html. As far as I understand this is the best practice. (e.g. http://stevesouders.com/hpws/css-bottom.php)

Anyhow, recently I have experienced different results.
Instead the codes below will return blank page when test.css is slow, which means I am not experiencing progressive rendering.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>
Blah..
</body>
</html>
```

Then when putting test.css at bottom, I get progressive rendering.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Blah..
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</body>
</html>
```

As far as I have understood and tought so far, it should be the other way round..
Probably there are other factors that I have overlooked?

Comment: What size is your CSS? (Wow, *that* feels awkward)

Comment: @vzwick filesize of CSS is of no importance. CSS should always be defined in `<head>`.

Comment: AFAIK, the files that "should" be at the end of your document are scripts, not styles.

Comment: My issue is with "blank white page" when css is downloading slowly. I first noticed this when I am encountering network issues. But regardless my understanding is that when css is downloading I should at least see some HTML contents first hence progressing rendering...but instead is css takes 10 seconds to download, I am seeing blank white page for 10 seconds. My understanding in order to achieve progressive rendering, putting css within <head></head> will do the trick. But it seems like this is not the case...

Comment: Also, now I am simulating the issues by doing a sleep(10) in css (css generated via PHP)...

Comment: @forestclown You might want to [Google for "FOUC"](http://www.google.com/search?q=fouc) (flash of unstyled content).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Google is fast busting the tradition of styles 'belonging' in the head. They do indeed recommend that critical styling belongs either in the `<head>` tag or even inline, but that other, non-essential styles should be referenced after the closing `</html>` tag. This does work on most, if not all modern browsers (I've not tested all).

The reason behind this is to load the bulk of the styles as a non-blocking reference, allowing the browser to begin writing to page before getting all the (potentially) bulky styles. Depending on what's in the 'critical' styles, this could cause an initial layout of hideous proportions before styling is rendered ([FOUC](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css%20FOUC&oq=css%20FOUC&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4229j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)). That is probably what you are experiencing with the "blank page" issue.

Remember also that CSS was released almost 20 years ago (1996), so it's not surprising that Google (and others) are manipulating and pushing out the traditional parameters of the concept.

A ridiculously simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>It's a Brave New World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/critical_styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- best page ever -->
</body>
</html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bulky_nonessential_styles.css" />
```

Comment: @Coomie, but do your visitors?

Comment: _They do indeed recommend_ please provide link

Comment: That's invalid html https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input - I'm not sure if that was a typo, but it should be safe to append the styles before the end of the body

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. I was reading elsewhere that rendering styles always blocked rendering

Comment: There is such conflicting information on this. As "best practice" it should be in the head, however Google Page Speed insights will complain about any render blocking files.

Answer (score 6):

CSS should be defined in your `<head>`.

This way, as elements are loading in the DOM, they will render with the proper styles applied immediately.

Comment: I have edited my question, my intention is how to solve the blank page issue..thanks for the info as well!

Answer (score 1):

It is worth remembering that when your browser first loads a CSS file, it usually caches it, although Internet Explorer does not cache CSS files loaded by other files using @import.

So next time around when a page is loaded, the cached version is used with no speed issues. So really, the only issue might occur when a user first loads the page.

I put all my CSS in the `<head>` where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Conflicting information can be found all over the internet.

I would strongly suggest that as of today you place only critical CSS as blocking CSS and then the rest as non render blocking using the following method:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/css.css" media="none"  onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
```

This will use the `media` parameter as `none` which means it will not load at all, and then once the page as loaded `onload` swap to `all` thus forcing it to load.

Also read more up about the media attribute here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp

Comment: If it doesn't load at all, I would have expected the onload event to not fire?